# Secure Android-app with sensitive data & store encrypted in db

Tags: php, android, mysql

I have an Android app that adds data via a PHP page into a MySQL database (free edition). The data from the Android app must be forwarded securely to the PHP page. In the MySql database the data must be stored encrypted. And the solution must be free (it is in the context of an assignment for school). Someone any idea how I can realize this?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, I would hear what is your thoughts have you made some consideration

Comment: Read : https://mobilityfun.wordpress.com/2017/05/26/encryption-decryption-using-rsa-in-android/

Comment: Encrypt your traffic using Https, use POST and not GET. You can either use a self signed certificate (you'll need to trust it in your code then) or go with a solution like letsencrypt (which won't work if you don't have a domain). Do you really have to encrypt the data or is it maybe enough to hash it? Encrypting the data in the database wouldn't make much sense if the decryption key was stored on your server as well, so either make sure that only the user holds the decryption key or omit it entirely.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have implemented a self-signed certificate but i am still looking for ways to trust the certificate in my Android code. In my app, i use a Async Task to send JSON data to the server.